# Getting info/networking with freelancers/contracters in the Silicon Valley

Tags: contracts, freelancing, retirement

I have 20 years of experience with 10 years in the Bay Area. Till recently I did a full time job for companies like eBay and Google. I recently retired. However, I feel like retiring full time might be too boring and would like to do some contract/freelancing work 3 months a year or more. I am finding it really difficult to find people in the same boat and unable to even find proper hourly contract rates etc. I was wondering if there are any groups or forums where I could network or find some info. How much would be hourly rate of a Java Developer with 20 years of experience who has worked for some decent companies?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Freelancing Stack Exchange](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> How much would be hourly rate of a Java Developer with 20 years of
> experience who has worked for some decent companies?

Since you are retired you have flexibility in what you charge. If you are a freelancer you normally need to cover not just your wages but PTO, retirement funds, insurance and the like.

If some of this is no longer needed then you may be able to charge less than the rule of thumb of twice your salary.

So If you used to make $100K a year the rule of thumb would be to charge 2* 100,000/2080 which is close enough to $100 an hour.

> I recently retired. However, I feel like retiring full time might be
> too boring and would like to do some contract/freelancing work 3
> months a year or more.

You have to decide if the income is more important than the time. Volunteering or tutoring are also options, without the income factor.